# Did I show sufficiency and minimal sufficiency correctly?

Tags: sufficient-statistics

I am currently trying to show that the statistic $\sum\limits_{y = 1}^n Y_i^2$ is minimal sufficient for $\mu$ where $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ is a random
sample from $N(\mu,\mu)$ for $\mu > 0$.

The textbook *All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference* by Larry Wasserman gives the following definitions and theorems:

> **9.32 Definition.** *Write $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ if $f(x^n; \theta) = cf(y^n; \theta)$ for some constant $c$ that might depend on $x^n$ and $y^n$ but not $\theta$. A statistic $T(x^n)$ is **sufficient** if $T(x^n) \leftrightarrow T(y^n)$ implies that $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$.*

> **9.35 Definition.** A statistic $T$ is **minimal sufficient** if (i) it is sufficient; and (ii) it is a function of every other sufficient statistic.

> **9.36 Theorem.** $T$ *is minimal sufficient if the following is true:*
> $$T(x^n) = T(y^n) \ \text{if and only if} \ x^n \leftrightarrow y^n.$$

> **9.40 Theorem** (Factorization Theorem). *$T$ is sufficient if and only if there are functions $g(t, \theta)$ and $h(x)$ such that $f(x^n; \theta) = g(t(x^n), \theta)h(x^n)$.*

I first calculate the likelihood

$$\begin{align} L(\mu; \mathbf{y}) &= \prod_{i = 1}^n L(\mu; y_i) \\ &= \prod_{i = 1}^n \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \mu}} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu}(y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= \dfrac{1}{(2 \pi \mu)^{n/2}} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \mu + \sum_{i = 1}^n \mu^2 \right) \right\}} \\ &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}} \end{align}$$

Using the factorization theorem, I get

$$\begin{align}&T(\mathbf{Y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2, \\ &g(T(\mathbf{y}), \mu) = (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}},\\ &h(\mathbf{y}) = 1, \end{align}$$

so we get

$$\begin{align} L(\mu; \mathbf{y}) = g(T(\mathbf{y}), \mu) \times h(\mathbf{y}) = (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}} \end{align}$$

I then conclude that the statistic $T(\mathbf{Y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2$ is sufficient for $\mu$.

I now have the likelihood ratio

$$\begin{align} \dfrac{L(\mu; \mathbf{y_1})}{L(\mu; \mathbf{y_2})} &= \exp{\left\{ \dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i}^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i}^2 + 2\mu \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i} \right) \right) \right\}} \\ &= \exp{\left\{ \dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i}^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i}^2 \right) + \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i} \right) \right\}} \end{align}$$

This likelihood ratio does not depend on the parameter $\mu$ iff $T(\mathbf{y}_2) = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i}^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i}^2 = T(\mathbf{y}_1)$:
$$\begin{align} \exp{\left\{ \dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i}^2 - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i}^2 \right) + \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i} \right) \right\}}  = \exp{\left\{ \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{1i} - \sum_{i = 1}^n y_{2i} \right) \right\}}
\end{align}$$

I then conclude that the statistic $T(\mathbf{Y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2$ is minimal sufficient.

However, I'm not sure whether I did this all correctly in accordance with the above definitions and theorems. The problem is that some of these are "iff", meaning that they require you to show the two-way implication (otherwise known as 'equivalence'), and I'm not sure that I did this correctly. The user microhaus posted [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/520330/163242) related answer, but I'm not sure if I've applied it correctly. First, I'm unsure whether my use of the factorization theorem was correct to conclude that the statistic $T(\mathbf{Y}) = \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2$ is sufficient for $\mu$. And second, I'm unsure how one is supposed to show that a statistic is "a function of every other sufficient statistic".

So is my work here correct? Did I use the factorization theorem correctly to conclude that the statistic is sufficient? How does one show that a statistic is "a function of every other sufficient statistic"? If there are any problems here, how can the reasoning be improved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [AoS](https://amzn.to/3tADdgX), there are definitions and there are theorems. Theorems are helpful in identifying properties. When achieving the equality
$$L(\mu;\mathbf y) = (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}$$
the exponential can be broken into parts
\begin{align}
L(\mu;\mathbf y) =& (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp \left\{ -\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2}{2 \mu} \right\} \exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\} \exp\left\{- n\mu/2 \right\}\\
=& \underbrace{(2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp\left\{- n\mu/2 \right\}^{(a)}}_\text{function of $\mu$ only} \underbrace{\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2}{2 \mu} \right\}^{(b)}}_\text{function of $(\mu,T(\mathbf y))$} \underbrace{\exp \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\}
^{(c)}}_\text{function of $y$ only} 
\end{align}

**Theorem 9.40** thus shows that $T(\mathbf y)$ is *sufficient* since $L(\mu;\mathbf y)$ *factorises* into a function of $(\mu,T(\mathbf y))$ [first two terms, *(a)* and *(b)*] times a function of $y$ only [last term *(c)*].

**Theorem 9.36** shows that $T(\mathbf y)$ is minimal* sufficient since, assuming that ["only if" part]$$T(\mathbf y)=T(\mathbf x)$$ this implies that only *(c)* differs between $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf x$ *[this is true for any sufficient statistic]* and, conversely ["if" part], if the equality $$L(\mu;\mathbf y)=c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)L(\mu;\mathbf x)\qquad \forall\mu\in\mathbb R^+$$holds, then
$$\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{T(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} \right\}\exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\}=c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu} \right\}\exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i\right\} \qquad \forall\mu\in\mathbb R^+$$
implies that
$$\exp \left\{ \dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu}-\dfrac{T(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} \right\}= c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)\exp \left\{ \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i-\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\}$$
i.e., the lhs is a constant function of $\mu$. Therefore, $$T(\mathbf y)=T(\mathbf x)$$
and the necessary and sufficient condition is established.

By applying **Theorem 9.36** to the question, one does not need to further establish that $T(\mathbf y)$ is a function of every sufficient statistic for this model, since **Theorem 9.36** provides a sufficient condition for minimal sufficiency to hold.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Can you please explain how $$\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{T(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} \right\}\exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\}=c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu} \right\}\exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n x_i\right\}\qquad \forall\mu\in\mathbb R^+$$ implies that $$\exp \left\{ \dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu}-\dfrac{T(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} \right\}$$ is a constant function of $\mu$? I understand that we can get $\exp \left\{ \dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu}-\dfrac{T(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} \right\}$ through division of the exponential on the RHS.

Comment: You just need to move the$$\exp \left\{ -\dfrac{T(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu} \right\}$$term from the rhs to the lhs and the$$\exp\left\{\sum_{i = 1}^n y_i\right\}$$term from the lhs to the rhs.

Comment: Wow, this is great. Thanks!