# How do we conclude that a statistic is sufficient but not minimal sufficient? #2

Tags: sufficient-statistics

This is related to [a question I recently asked](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520269/163242).

I want to show that the statistic $\left(\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i, \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 \right)$ is sufficient for $\mu$ but *not* minimal sufficient where $(Y_1, \dots, Y_n)$ is a random sample from $N(\mu, \mu)$ for $\mu > 0$.

The textbook *All of Statistics: A Concise Course in Statistical Inference* by Larry Wasserman gives the following definition and theorem of minimal sufficiency:

> **9.32 Definition.** *Write $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ if $f(x^n; \theta) = cf(y^n; \theta)$ for some constant $c$ that might depend on $x^n$ and $y^n$ but not $\theta$. A statistic $T(x^n)$ is **sufficient** if $T(x^n) \leftrightarrow T(y^n)$ implies that $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$.*

> **9.35 Definition.** A statistic $T$ is **minimal sufficient** if (i) it is sufficient; and (ii) it is a function of every other sufficient statistic.

> **9.36 Theorem.** $T$ *is minimal sufficient if the following is true:*
> $$T(x^n) = T(y^n) \ \text{if and only if} \ x^n \leftrightarrow y^n.$$

Using theorem 9.36 as a guide, how do we show *in practice* that a statistic is *not* minimal sufficient?

For the statistic $T(\mathbf{Y}) = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i, \sum_{i = 1}^n Y_i^2 \right)$, let's assume that $T(\mathbf{Y}) = T(\mathbf{X})$. I calculated the likelihood
$$\begin{align} L(\mu; \mathbf{y}) &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}} \end{align},$$
and so we also have
$$\begin{align} L(\mu; \mathbf{x}) &= (2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}} \end{align}.$$
Taking the ratio of these, as in definition 9.32, we get
$$\begin{align} \dfrac{L(\mu; \mathbf{y})}{L(\mu; \mathbf{x})} &= \dfrac{(2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}}{(2\pi \mu)^{-n/2} \exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}} \\ &= \dfrac{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}}{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i + n\mu^2 \right) \right\}}} \\ &= \dfrac{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \right) \right\}}}{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \right) \right\}}} \end{align}$$

Is this the type of calculation that we need to do? I don't really understand what I'm doing here, partly because I don't really understand how $c$ in definition 9.32 is supposed to work in practice.

Comment: This is essentially asking the [same question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520269/163242). In the [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520269/163242) you show that $T^0(\mathbf y)=\sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2$ is _minimal sufficient_. This implies that (a) $T^1(\mathbf y)=(T^0(\mathbf y),\sum_{i=1}^n y_i)$ is sufficient [since it contains $T^0$] and (b) it is not minimal [since it is not a function of $T^0$].

Comment: Could you erase and rewrite the previous comment as the sentence about $T^0$ not being a function of $T^0$ does not make sense. My point is that $\sum_i y_i$ cannot be expressed as a function of $\sum_i y_i^2$. If I know that $\sum_i y_i^2=3.1415$, I cannot find the numerical value of $\sum_i y_i$ (even when $n=1$).

Comment: @Xi'an and The Pointer. Having re-read my answer to [the linked question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520269/how-do-we-conclude-that-a-statistic-is-sufficient-but-not-minimal-sufficient), I have realised that I could be more explicit in showing why $U = (\sum Y_i, \sum Y^2_i)$ is sufficient but *not* minimal sufficient, I will edit accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply¹ **Theorem 9.36**, **the relevant implication for minimality is that  $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ implies $T(x^n) = T(y^n)$** (as the reverse implication always holds for any sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf y)$).

Hence if one starts from the property $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ holding for a given pair $(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)$, it means that
$$L(\mu;\mathbf y)=c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)L(\mu;\mathbf x)\qquad \forall\mu\in\mathbb R^+$$
where $c(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)$ is a function of $(\mathbf y,\mathbf x)$ *that does not depend on $\mu$*. As correctly developped in the question
\begin{align}
\dfrac{L(\mu;\mathbf y)}{L(\mu;\mathbf x)}
&= \dfrac{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n y_i \right) \right\}}}{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{1}{2 \mu} \left( \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu \sum_{i = 1}^n x_i \right) \right\}}}\\
\end{align}
Regrouping terms together
\begin{align}
\dfrac{L(\mu;\mathbf y)}{L(\mu;\mathbf x)}
&=\dfrac{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{T_1(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu} + T_2(\mathbf y)  \right\}}}{\exp{\left\{ -\dfrac{T_1(\mathbf x)}{2 \mu} + T_2(\mathbf x)  \right\}}}
=\dfrac{\exp{\left\{ \dfrac{T_1(\mathbf x)-T_1(\mathbf y)}{2 \mu}    \right\}}}{\exp{\left\{ T_2(\mathbf x) - T_2(\mathbf y) \right\}}}
\end{align}
where $T(\mathbf y)=(T_1(\mathbf y),T_2(\mathbf y))$. This ratio being constant in $\mu$ by assumption, this implies
$$T_1(\mathbf y)=T_1(\mathbf x)$$
rather than the intended
$$T(\mathbf y)=T(\mathbf x)$$
Therefore $T(\mathbf y)$ is not minimal by virtue of **Theorem 9.6**.

---

¹A direct argument made in my comment is that, since $T_1(\mathbf y)$ [is a minimal statistic](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/520269/163242), the pair $(T_1(\mathbf y),T_2(\mathbf y))$ cannot be a minimal statistic.

Comment: Thank you for supplying a much more direct way of getting the solution than the one I originally supplied [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520269/how-do-we-conclude-that-a-statistic-is-sufficient-but-not-minimal-sufficient/520330#520330). Reading your solution was instructive for me also.

Comment: @microhaus: Thanks for the support, I have not first realised [The Pointer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/163242/the-pointer) had somehow posted the question three times over the past days.

Comment: I guess they are being thorough, and sometimes it helps to see multiple ways of getting the same answer. For example, the part of your solution which states "*the relevant implication for minimality is that $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ implies $T(x^n) =T(y^n)$ (as the reverse implication always holds for any sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf{y})$).*" is a point of emphasis that is new to me.

Comment: @Xi'an The questions are on the same subject, but they are asking different things (different aspects of the same subject).

Comment: "To apply **Theorem 9.36**, **the relevant implication for minimality is that  $x^n \leftrightarrow y^n$ implies $T(x^n) = T(y^n)$** (as the reverse implication always holds for any sufficient statistic $T(\mathbf y)$)." Good point to know. This would have saved me some time had I known it earlier.